# Extra Large VB Case Statement

Tags: switch-statement, case

Right now I have a large program that has a very very large set of models for different types of items. Each case sets the properties of said items, and then we use it so.

For example:

```
Select Case Animal
Case "Dalamatian", "Collie","Lab"
 .Legs = 4
 .Ears = "Floppy"
 .FurIsFuzzy = True
Case "Elephant"
.Legs = 4
.HasTrunk = True
.HasTusks = True
Case "Panda", "Polar" 
.IsBear = True
```

You get the idea. All the models have different properties, different values. The code I inherited has **2,000** models (and about 100+ cases!). Which is terribly inefficient. From the archive here I've noticed some similar questions on doing this by making a dictionary of methods or possibly polymorphism. Any other possible suggestions for VB.net for this issue? I was thinking of a look-up table possibly, but I don't know of the processing cost of that in comparison to the case/switch statement.
 Any ideas? Or should I just leave the monster as is?

Thanks guys.

Comment: The code is not inefficient but unmaintainable.

Comment: This might be a question for [code review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would suggest that it is both, at least if I understand the question correctly. The implementation of this results in the comparison of 100,000 strings on average. Using a hash would reduce this to 2000 hash lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've not read Refactoring to Patterns, I'd highly recommend it. This sounds like a good example of using the Command pattern, which is basically what the dictionary of methods accomplishes.

From a read-ability standpoint, I'd recommend using Extract Method first. Once that's completed, you could replace the case statement with a shared dictionary. Something like this:

```
Public Shared commands As New Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of AnimalClass))()

' In your constructor
If commands.Count = 0 then
commands.Add("Dalmation",InitializeAsDog)
commands.Add("Collie",InitializeAsDog)
commands.Add("Lab",InitializeAsDog)
...
End If

' Replace case statement with this:

Dim callback as Action = commands.Item(Animal)
callback(instanceOfAnimal)
```

This gives you O(1) efficiency for the refactoring, or O(2000) to initialize all of the models. Contrast this with the original case statement which requires 100 comparisons for each loop, roughly the equivalent of scanning an array until a match is found. This would be roughly O(100) efficient, or O(200000) to initialize all the models.

Answer (score 0):

B2K,

Hmm, that looks like a better solution. I agree, it's not necessarily the inefficiency, but the  maintaining that bothers me. The list is ever growing as we add more models to our software.

I'll definitely look up the book and give it a chance on this. I agree, we do need to reduce the comparisons.

Thanks!
K